# iOS WKWebView HTML5 Audio stops after about 30 seconds when phone is locked

Tags: html, ios, xcode, audio, background

We've created a iOS application which contains a hybrid web application. One of the features of our app is audio playback. This is accomplished using the HTML5 audio player. Since some audio files can get quite long, most users lock (or autolock) their iOS device.

We've tried the same case on multiple iOS devices. This works fine in most cases, but on some devices the audio playback stops after a random time at around 30 ~ 60 seconds. We've tried enabling the Audio Background Mode in the Info plist, without success.

Answer (score 2):

Is a known bug in IOS 13, see these links:

- https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/121822
- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=204261

Comment: is there any solution?

Comment: Play it in the native context using AVPlayer seems to be solution [AVPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer)